# Macro to insert hyperlink based on specific text entered in cell

Tags: excel, hyperlink

Working on an inspection checklist,
Users instructed to enter "Ok" or "X" in cell.
Sheet columns are the months and the rows are the components being inspected. If user enters an "X", I want that cell to automatically change to a hyperlink with the cell still displaying an "X"   The hyperlink should take the user to Sheet2 in the workbook where they will enter exception information. Needs to be for multiple columns.
Here is what I have, but it does not work.  Thanks for any help you might have.

```
Sub Exceptions()
'
' Exceptions Macro

' Macro recorded 12/9/2010 by
'

'
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inspection").Range("B9").Range("B100").Value = "X" Then
  ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "Exceptions!A1", TextToDisplay:="X"


End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will add a hyperlink to sheet Exceptions range A1 if a user types a 'x' or 'X' into any cell anywhere in sheet 1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target = "x" Or Target = "X" Then
    Target.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Target, Address:="", SubAddress:="Exceptions!A1", TextToDisplay:=Target.Value
End If

End Sub
```

A few things to note:

1. This code must be placed in the `Worksheet_Change` event of sheet 1
2. If you only want to add hyperlinks to certain columns / rows then you will need to update the code above. Let me know if you need help using the comment functionality at the bottom of this post

**Update - limit hyperlinks to certain rows / columns**

If you want to limit the hyperlinks to certain areas of code then use this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rangeLimit As Range

//Set you rangeLimit accordingly. Examples shown below...

Set rangeLimit = Range("A1:A10") // Only allow hyperlinks in range A1 to A10
Set rangeLimit = Range("A1:A10,B1:B5") // Only allow hyperlinks in range A1 to A10 and B1 to B5
Set rangeLimit = Range("A:A,C:C") // Only allow hyperlinks in columns A and C

If Not Intersect(rangeLimit, Target) Is Nothing Then
    If Target = "x" Or Target = "X" Then
         Target.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Target, Address:="", SubAddress:="Sheet2!A1", TextToDisplay:=Target.Value
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: This works great.  I would like to limit to certain rows or columns.  Any help would be most appreciated.  Thank you!!

Comment: No rush.  Thank you for your help.  I am excited about getting this working.

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  Thank you again for your help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Ran in to a little problem. If I try to paste multiple cells that are in the range in the code below, I get a run time error 13, type mismatch.  The cells in the range may have data other than X but I only want the hyperlink to appear if the cell contains X.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim rangeLimit As Range
 
     Set rangeLimit = Range      ("B9:B37,C9:C37,D9:D37,E9:E37,F9:F37,G9:G37,H9:H37,I9:I37,J9:J37,K9:K37,L9:L37,M9:M37")
 
     If Not Intersect(rangeLimit, Target) Is Nothing Then
         If Target = "x" Or Target = "X" Then
         Target.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Target, Address:=""SubAddress:="Exceptions!A1", TextToDisplay:=Target.Value
    
    End If
    
    End If

    End Sub